# How to find hotels with helipads?

Tags: online-resources, hotels, luxury, helicopters

Is there any website or app where you can find hotels with helipads?

I really want to take a helicopter to a hotel and I think using the internet is the best way to find a hotel with a helipad or some other place you can land.

When Uber launch their heli-taxi service this will be extremely relevant information.

Comment: If you want to know because you need to land your helicopter there, I would imagine asking one of your three personal assistants to research the matter would be a good idea.

Comment: Neither Alexa, Cortana nor Siri can help me with this. They're just chatting about the weather all the time no matter what I ask them to do, @DJClayworth.

Comment: I suggest taking all your helicopter questions to aviation.stackexchange.com. There may be some databases or charts, or you may need to have a local pilot who knows the area and where landing is permitted under what conditions. The aviation people are much more likely to know that travel.

Comment: As a reminder, questions on Stack Exchange 1) should be practical, real-life questions. Extremely few hotels in the world have helipads, because helipads are extremely noisy places, so you need to explain why you have this particular need. 2) Questions are expected to demonstrate some initial research efforts. Did you do a web search? Did you post on any helicoptering forums? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: There are charts for helicopter use. Most pilots are switching from paper to electronic charts with apps like ForeFlight. AOPA has one for its members. Or, you can download them in PDF format from https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/vfr/

Comment: Another tool to use in your search is https://skyvector.com/ . Although, this too may prove fruitless. Hotel helipads are for private use and not public use. Unlike private use airstrips, which are depicted on charts to serve as visual reference points and emergency only landing options, private helipads do not seem to appear as much. With just a quick glance, I only count 5  heliports on the chart containing the island of Manhattan. Also, the charts may make a distinction between helipads and official heliports (which may have multiple helipads).

Comment: Here is another list of heliports. They are official heliports and not just helipads. They are also private use for public entities (like government buildings, police stations, and hospitals). Not the same as luxury hotels. https://airnav.com/airports/us/NY?type=H&use=R

Comment: Ultimately, you have to call the hotel directly. You or your pilot would have to do that anyway to arrange for permission to land or even to hover near or fly within 500 feet (not an officially regulated distance). There also may be further restrictions on altitude or restricted areas (like Trump Tower) imposed by the FAA.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Hotels with helipads and regulae transfer services exist, and it's a pretty short enumerable list.  I've kicked off a wiki for this.

Comment: It's quite an unusual question, but it's a practical one and I don't understand the downvotes. I have had remarks in questions I did in the past when I ask for cheap things since cheap is relative. Expensive and practicality is also relative. One might not like the question for many reasons but the fact is that it's a valid one. Some people can afford helicopters and in some cities in the world, it's even common for richer people to travel this way.

Comment: Unless you're picking your destination purely on whether it has hotels with helipads. I'd suggest picking a destination, then contacting local helicopter companies to ask which (if any) hotels have helipads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if there's a comprehensive resource, but it's going to be a pretty limited list, so here's a community wiki for it.  For inclusion, the hotel must both have their own helipad (flights nearby don't count) *and* offer regular, bookable helicopter transfer services (unused/emergency-only helipads don't count):

- **The Peninsula, Hong Kong**. If the Rolls just isn't enough, private helicopter transfers from Hong Kong airport for you and your 5 best buddies for a mere 26,500 HKD (~3600 USD) one way. Source: https://www.peninsula.com/en/-/media/files/hong-kong/at-a-glance/phk-airport-transfer-en_04122017-(1).pdf (PDF)
- Shangri-La Jakarta, Indonesia
- ITC Royal Gardenia, Bangalore, India
- Ciragan Kempinski, Istanbul, Turkey
- Le Mirador Kempinski, Vevey, Switzerland

The last four sourced from https://www.businesstraveller.com/news/2012/07/11/five-hotels-with-helipads/ (2012).

No longer on the list:

- The Peninsula, Bangkok.  Taking this was on my personal bucket list, but they appear to have stopped their service, which not only was a snip at a mere $1000/one way (in 2005) but let you check in via their dedicated Sky Lounge too, without ever having to descend to the street level where mere mortals dwell.  Sigh.